# CHEF Scipt with embedded BASH/SED command: unexpected `}'

Tags: bash, sed, chef-infra

Trying to execute SED against a file from chef is yielding an error, that I am having trouble tracking down

It runs without issue from the console:

```
sed -i.bak -e "\$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT" /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif
```

However from my recipe:

```
bash 'UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif #3' do
  code <<-EOH
     sed -i.bak -e "\$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT" /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif
  EOH
end
```

I am getting the following error

```
    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif #3]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20151029-7070-y3iz58" ----
    STDOUT: 
    STDERR: sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unexpected `}'
    ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20151029-7070-y3iz58" ----
    Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20151029-7070-y3iz58" returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/3rd-open-ldap-server/recipes/default.rb

     64: bash 'UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif #3' do
     65:   code <<-EOH
     66:      sed -i.bak -e "\$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT" /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif
     67:   EOH
     68: end
     69: bash 'UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif #4' do

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/3rd-open-ldap-server/recipes/default.rb:64:in `from_file'

    bash("UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif #3") do
      action [:run]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      command "UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\\=config/olcDatabase\\=\\{2\\}bdb.ldif #3"
      backup 5
      returns 0
      code "     sed -i.bak -e \"$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT\" /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif\n"
      interpreter "bash"
      declared_type :bash
      cookbook_name "3rd-open-ldap-server"
      recipe_name "default"
    end
```

Confusingly I don't know what character 8 is. I suspect that it is some sort of escaping issue - but I have no idea where.

---

Update (to provide insight to where it is not): I think it is in the sed command and not the file name as this command works without issue from chef:

```
bash 'UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif #2' do
  code <<-EOH
     sudo sed -i.bak s/dc=my-domain,dc=com/dc=my,dc=lan/g /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif
  EOH
end
```

Comment: I believe your escaping backslash is being eaten by some of your nesting levels. Can you get that command to work (in the heredoc) from outside of chef? I'm betting you need to add two more backslashes to the one you already have (and possibly even more than that if chef is unescaping things as well).

Comment: @EtanReisner, I'm not sure it's two more -- might be only one, since the heredoc is in this context a Ruby construct rather than a bash one here. Can you explain?

Comment: I am fairly certain the problem is coming in this portion of the command:   sed -i.bak -e "\$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT" but I have tried to escape the } once and twice without effect...  Could I / SHould I need to escape the first /?

Comment: Actuallyu that looks to possibly be it - very misleading message

Comment: @akaphenom, btw, the way I would have started debugging this would have been to use strace, sysdig or similar to see what was *actually* being passed to the shell from Chef.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am new  to chef, and learning - I will review those tools and see what they are telling me.  Thanks

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You may very well be correct. I wrote the answer before I noticed whose heredoc this was.

Comment: I know you asked a specific question but if you need to just add the text to the end of the file, I'd probably rewrite it  `echo text >>  /etc/openldap...`, it's more readable that way. To answer the question, try a string literal: E.g. `sed $'\$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT'`

Comment: `bash -c "sed  $'$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT' <<< "lsjkfdlksjdflksjdfs""
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unexpected `}'` With the backslash, it goes through unless Chef drops it through another shell, if so add a few more backslashes. `bash -c "sed  $'\$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT' <<< "lsjkfdlksjdflksjdfs""
lsjkfdlksjdflksjdfs
olcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to double escape the $ at the start of the sed expression:

```
bash 'UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif #3' do
  code <<-EOH
     sed -i.bak -e "\\$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT" /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif
  EOH
end
```

Comment: If you used single rather than double quotes, you wouldn't have had that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that there is some environment being set up when you wrap the command where the `$a...` is getting some bogus shell var substitution done on it. What if you just use single quotes and ditch the `\` to try to prevent any such thing?

I.e.:

```
bash 'UPDATE /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif #3' do
  code <<-EOH
     sed -i.bak -e '$aolcRootPW: {SSHA}Z/+CHVP/Vx3bA2m6l0aI6uvIMhJUitpT' /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{2\}bdb.ldif
  EOH
end
```